# Angular en C# Core

Tags: c#, angular, visual-studio, asp.net-mvc, angular-cli

Estoy utilizando Visual Studio 2017 C# Framework 7.2 y Angular 2.1 CLI. Saniticé el Angular para poder incorporar script con `<script></script>` en el Index.html. Tengo plugins que cargan bien en los archivos .ts al incorporar esto en el  ngOnInit():

```
 (function ($) {
  $(document).ready(function () {
    $('#txtFechaProduccion').datepicker({
      format: "dd/mm/yyyy",
      language: "es",
      autoclose: true
    });
  });
})(jQuery);
```

Pero tengo otros script que no utilizan esta lógica de $('id').Plugins(); sino que se ejecutan con clases específicas o con datos que se colocan en los formularios como :

```
              <textarea id="txtDescripcion" rows="3" cols="3" maxlength="200" class="form-control maxlength-textarea" placeholder="Default textarea"></textarea>
```

En este caso el script (http://www.formvalidator.net/) se aplica al leer la clase "maxlength-textarea" pero sólo me funcionan si recargo la página, y no es la idea que deba recargar la página para que el Script se ejecute si estoy utilizando Angular.

Reviso la consola y no veo ningún error que tenga que ver con eso, no se si me pueden ayudar o les ha pasado para saber como resolverlo.

Saludos !

Comment: revisa cuales referencias de javascript se cargan al principio y cuales despues, puedes comparar las dos salidas para que encuentres que te falta cargar la primera vez

Comment: Ya probé eso pero todo carga bien.

Comment: angular cuenta ya con librerias para validacion de datos procura no mezclar librerias de jquery , angular, javascript te dan mas problemas que soluciones si decidiste usar angular usa todo el ecosistema de angular es facil